# Azure Grafana Instance plugin installation

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-managed-grafana

I have created an Azure managed Grafana instance in the Azure portal ..So while trying to install some plugins(clock and polystat ) In the configuration section under plugins I was not able o find the install button that is normally visible for the locally hosted grafana . while searching for resources online I was not able to find any information about installaion of panel plugins for Azure managed grafana instance .It would be really helpful if there are some links or documents regd the installation of plugins on azure grafana instance .If there are some commands in azure grafana cli for installation of plugins please give an example command for that (Saw coomands for creation deletion etc of dashboards but didnt see any info on plugin installation for panels)

Answer (score 3):

Doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/managed-grafana/#faq is your friend:

> Can I install my own plugin?
>
> Due to security concerns, Azure Managed Grafana doesn't currently support custom plugins.

So you can't install custom plugins (except some Grafana Enterprise plugins; clock and polystat are definitely not a enteprise plugins).